# VB.Net Class Inherit Sub New

Tags: vb.net, class

I'm currently trying to convert some basics in C# class methods into VB, and I'm having some difficulties.

Say we have two classes, `baseClass` and `newClass`

```
Public Class baseClass
    Public Sub New(ByVal obj As Object)
       '... do something here
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class newClass
    Inherits baseClass
    Public Sub New(ByVal obj as Object)
       '... do something here
    End Sub
end Class
```

However, whenever I tried to declear something like

```
dim nc as newClass(myObj)
```

I kept getting an error telling me that

`First statement of this 'Sub New' must be a call to 'MyBase.New' or 'MyClass.New' because base class 'baseClass' of 'newClass' does not have an accessible 'Sub New' that can be called with no arguments.`

When I was trying to do something like, if written in C#, like this

```
public partial class newClass : baseClass
{
  public newClass(Object obj) : baseClass(obj)
  {
     // do something here
  }
}
```

I understand that the debugger is telling me just add an empty `public sub new()` in `baseClass`, but that's not what I'm trying to do, I wanted it to invoke the other constructor, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, since I've been trying to find an easy conversion guide but I couldn't find any.

Any answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Public Class newClass
    Inherits baseClass
    Public Sub New(ByVal obj as Object)
        MyBase.New(obj)
    End Sub
end Class
```